# Tag Merge: [fsm] [Finite-State-Machine]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

There seems to be at least two tags on Stack Overflow referring to Finite-State machines:

- [finite-state-machine](/questions/tagged/finite-state-machine) 178 questions tagged

  > Finite State Machine is a mathematical abstraction used as a behaviour model composed of a finite number of states, their transitions and functions to design digital logic or computer programs.
- [fsm](/questions/tagged/fsm) 185 questions tagged

  > Acronym for Finite State Machine.

Furthermore, both seem to overlap at least *somewhat* with [state](/questions/tagged/state).

I can't see how this is intentional, or benificial.

Comment: Per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22354706/1468366), perhaps [finite-automata] (215 questions tagged) should be included in this merge.